# The project structure is not shown correctly in the 'Project Tool Window'

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, mercurial, project

**The Situation**:
Suddednly, one of projects I work with, is seen in a very shorten way in the `Project tool window` :

```
.hgignore
.hgtags
External libraries
```

Those are all visible things in the `Project tool window`. On the main frame the file I worked with is shown. And all its path is seen in the navigation bar. From the `navigation bar` I can reach to all folders of the project. (It is a VERY large utility project, containing all static pages, images and things for many usual projects). Naturally, I would like to work normally, using `Projects tool window`. But there, as you can see, all folders are invisible.

Opening/closing of `project tool window`, IntelliJ `restart` or `cach invalidate and restart` won't help - the picture remains the same.

If I am adding a module to the project, it IS seen. If I am adding a folder to the project, it is NOT seen. All existing inner structure in the project is in folders, not modules.

**The Possible Reasons of the broke**:
All changes that I had made to the project by hand, is adding an image file. But from `TortoiseHg` I had made some updates. For other projects. That very project is not even in the Tortoise list of repositories. But as I had loaded the project from repository sometimes, it is known by hg. All other team members see the project normally.

**Target**:
I would like to see the project back in all its beauty.

Comment: add a Module...

Comment: I have added a module. Now I see in project tool window that module. And only it is added, but all older folders remain invisible.

Comment: If you open module settings are the 'missing' folders marked as `Excluded`?

Comment: Project Structure - Module window is empty. But I don't think it is a problem, for the project simply has all its folders as folders, not modules. Oh! Added folder is unseen, too.